# Best Way for handling HTTP 503 in post request

Tags: java, http-post

Im currently hitting a service with a post request were I use HttpsURLConnection and call conn.getOutputStream() to write the payload to the connection.

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(Payload);
```

If the connection has already returned a http 503 service unavailable response I get a java.io.IOException when trying to write to the output stream and if I check for this 503 response using:

```
conn.getResponseCode()
```

before writting to the output stream I then get the exception:

```
"java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input"
```

Im just wondering if there is a prefered way to handle this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you _"...check for this 503 response before writting to the output stream I then get the exception..."_

Comment: just by calling conn.getResponseCode() .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `conn.getResponseCode()` the request will be sent and the response will be read. Therefore it is not possible anymore to write to the output stream.

Catch the IOException and use `conn.getResponseCode()` to get more information about the cause of the exception:

```
try {

  ...
  DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
  os.writeBytes(Payload);
  ...

} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
  conn.getResponseCode();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - a note, I then also have to wrap the conn.getResponseCode() in its own try catch statment which I handle.  Nothing too tricky but thought it worth noting.  Thanks again.